# Vue <template> in a .vue file with Lodash

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, lodash

In my .vue file within my template section I have:

```
<a v-bind:href="'javascript:artist(\'' + _.escape(artist) + '\')'">
```

which is using the Lodash function _.escape. This generates a string of errors the first of which is:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "_" is not defined on the instance but referenced during 
render.
```

However in the same file in the script section of the component I am happily and successfully using a range of Lodash functions.

This is a Laravel app and in my app.js file I have this code:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

window.Vue.use(VueRouter);

import lodash from 'lodash';
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$lodash', { value: lodash });

import SearchHome from './components/search.vue';

const routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    components: {
        searchHome: SearchHome
    }
},
```

]

```
const router = new VueRouter({ routes })

const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app')
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I have also tried <a v-bind:href="'javascript:artist(\'' + this.$lodash.escape(artist) + '\')'">

Comment: SORRY! I have solved it. It should of course be $lodash.escape().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a computed value instead. This will improve readability.
Avoid complex operation in a binding.

```
<a :href="artistLink">
```

And in the script

```
import _ from 'lodash'

export default {
    computed: {
       artistLink () {
           return 'javascript:artist(\'' + _.escape(this.artist) + '\')'
       }
    }
}
```